# Deploy Java Appication using Azure DevOps Release deployment group

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I have successfully built and deplyed Asp.net application on my laptop's IIS using "IIS website and SQL database Deploment" template from Release pipeline of azure devops. However, I wish to now deploy Java-Spring application.

The application is built successfully using Azure DevOps build pipeline. However, I could not find any template to install java application on premises.. Also, I am not a java developer but .NET Developer.

[image]

Also was successfully able to deploy the java app to azure using template "Deploy a Java app to Azure App Service". Now I wish to do the same with any VM or my own laptop. Please help me to achieve the same.

Comment: Is that java web app, maybe you're looking for [Apache Tomcat Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60173617/deploy-java-appication-using-azure-devops-release-deployment-group).

Comment: @ToBeOrNotToBe Yes, but after clicking the link provided by you its pointing to my page only. Please help.

Comment: Check the link: [Deploy A New Application Archive (WAR) Remotely](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_Archive_(WAR)_Remotely)

Comment: Sorry for the wrong link, Check if [it](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.apachetomcat&ssr=false#overview) helps.